# React Starter Kit Reports Unexplained Missing Packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Let me start by stating that I am a rank beginner with respect to React/JS, but far from a beginner overall; my experience is varied, and includes, among many other things, some work with Angular/JS. Hence, this is not my first exposure to the Node/JS ecosystem.

The current investigation began with a missing peer report that I received when I installed the Material_UI package into the directory into which I had just installed the React Starter Kit, which gave the following report.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall F:\Praesidium\Armatus_Admin_EventRegistration\React\material_ui_table_demo\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

+ react-scripts@1.1.2
+ react@16.3.0
+ react-dom@16.3.0
added 1327 packages in 86.861s

Success! Created material_ui_table_demo at F:\Praesidium\Armatus_Admin_EventRegistration\React\material_ui_table_demo
Inside that directory, you can run several commands: ...
```

Installing Material_UI elicited the following report.

```
npm install material-ui@next

> jss@9.8.1 postinstall F:\Praesidium\Armatus_Admin_EventRegistration\React\material_ui_table_demo\node_modules\jss
> node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove JSS? You can now support us on open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/jss/donate\u001b[0m')"

Love JSS? You can now support us on open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/jss/donate
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ material-ui@1.0.0-beta.40
added 47 packages in 23.878s
```

After investigating the AJV package, I decided to generate a dependency tree from the starter kit. The dependency tree reported one peer dependency, on the aforementioned AJV package, *which went unreported by the installer*.

More puzzling, however, is the list of allegedly missing packages reported by **npm list**.

[material_ui_table_demo_Packages_Skeleton_20180402_211705.TXT](https://p6lists-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/p/dagray/EZm-ITUvS7lPk_YX88-1daoBqiKsD-IJSiJLjNyrsk3_yQ?e=FSfNij) is the **npm list** report covering the React Starter Kit.

[material_ui_table_demo_Packages_Skeleton_20180402_211705_STDOUT.TXT](https://p6lists-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/p/dagray/EYMYjtJCXZlDsRzDyMLxlK0BkHZsV2R4Il7Fo_Ui8WtOcQ?e=4EkMB1) is the list of missing packages, which were reported on the terminal console.

Since it affects the dependency tree, it is important that you are aware that this installation is on Microsoft Windows 10 Professional, and that the installed NPM and Node versions are 5.6.0 and v8.10.0, respectively.

The [React Starter Kit Installation Instructions](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html) are dead silent about unresolved dependencies that a developer must address. Which report do I believe, the dependency tree or the missing packages reported separately by the very same **npm list**?

Comment: I just discovered something else disturbing; in package-lock.json, I see ""ajv": {"version": "5.5.2" ..." Per https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json, this means that it must be version 5.5.2, period. This makes me hesitant to upgrade the AJV package.

Comment: is there a reason you didn't start with create-react-app ?

Comment: @azium, I did start with create-react-app? What makes you suspect otherwise? Though I launched it from a shell script, that shell script just prompts for an application name, then runs create-react-app.

Comment: This made me hesitant to upgrade the AJV package until I noticed further down that the table package lists version 6.4.0 as a requirement.

Comment: also, always trust what your local error report is saying. when in doubt, cd into your node_modules folder to make sure the correct packages are there. you can also try installing stuff with `yarn` to try it out. lastly, getting the @next version of any package will be more unstable than the last major release

Comment: ah sorry I didn't see it in your question and have never heard anyone call it the React Starter Kit, which used to refer to a zip file of old school scripts and index page, without a module bundler).

Comment: Fair enough. I borrowed that name from one of the React manual pages that I had open.

Comment: Though I wouldn't normally do @next, according to https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui, it's the recommended branch for Material_UI.

Comment: does your app fail to load? maybe if you're not using any components that require ajv you'll be fine

Comment: not sure if helpful or not.. osx sierra, create-react-app@1.4.3, node@8.4.0, material-ui@next, installed with yarn@1.3.2, did not receive any warnings

Comment: @azium, did you run npm list after you installed? That's what reported the errors.

Comment: no, why would you do that?

Comment: my casual response here is that... software sucks and breaks all the time, especially for package version reasons... it's not a showstopper. as long your app works you're good. if you want to make sure stuff works in prod, pin packages to exact versions or download local copies or shrinkwrap etc

Comment: So what's the real problem here? As it is, the problem statement is very convoluted and it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of not installing packages on the first `npm install` has been popping up up here in there.

Running `npm install` again for a second time usually solves the problem, but in some cases (like this) you have to **force a package version** by doing the following steps:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder
2. Delete the `package-lock.json`
3. Add the exact dependency to the `package.json` (in our case `ajv@^6.0.0`)
4. Execute `npm update` (just in case)
5. Execute `npm install`

Now the `pm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.0.0, required by ajv-keywords@3.1.0` is no longer!

Note: how to add the dependency:

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    ...
```

Why? Its a bug with the dependency system of npm (they added a hacky solution at some point and then they removed it, they have said they will rewrite the whole dependency system at some point)